# Crystal Report , Cross tabs and conditional formatting

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using a formula in my Crystal cross tab and cannot conditional format that field.  Is there a way to do that?  If I use Highlight expert I would have to add are variables.. I have a flag Y or N if the metrics is in range and I want all out of range to be red but that field (formula) does not show up in my list to pick from.  If I write a formulas under font color like If {RC_Agent_ReportCard_sp;1.Within_Goal} = 'N' then crRed else crBlack everything turn red ... Help

If I write a formulas under font color like If {RC_Agent_ReportCard_sp;1.Within_Goal} = 'N' then crRed else crBlack everything turn red ... Help

If I write a formulas under font color like If {RC_Agent_ReportCard_sp;1.Within_Goal} = 'N' then crRed else crBlack everything turn red ... Help

Comment: please format your question properly, e.g. formatting the code, errors, etc.

Comment: 1.  Does your CR formula use single quotes in the string comparison like your code here does, or is this just a typo here on your question?  Single quotes in this formula should cause Crystal Reports to throw a String Required Here error when trying to save this formula.

Comment: 2. If you place a field into your report to show the value of `{RC_Agent_ReportCard_sp;1.Within_Goal}`, what value does it print?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **GridRowColumnValue** in your formula. Because this will give you the current value of the cell in the cross tab grid. So the condition will be some thing like this:

```
 If GridRowColumnValue({RC_Agent_ReportCard_sp;1.Within_Goal}) = 'N'
 then crRed else crBlack
```

Thank you.

Comment: **'GridRowColumnValue'** is best thing to use in cross tab crystal report.